# "chmod" hadoop path from Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

What i am doing basically is automating some shell commands (theses commands including hadoop shell commands) using java code, now I am doing the follwoing commands on bash:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir path//tp//folder
hadoop fs -chmod a+w path//to//folder
```

everything working fine, now when to trying to use java code to perform the same actions:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdir(new Path("path//to//folder"),new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL))
```

unfortunately this  method:

```
public void setPermission(Path p, FsPermission permission) throws IOException 
{
}
```

is not implemented (respectively: *empty*) with hadoop v 2.6.0 ~ 2.8.0

My question how can i add read/write permission to hadoop path using java code?

Comment: Isn't the method `mkdirs`?

Comment: `FileSystem` is abstract, here is its implementation for hdfs:
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem.java

Have you tried to use this method? did you get error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you might want to cross-check the results of your analysis. If you look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java) for example, you find that FileSystem is actually an **abstract** class. So it wouldnt surprise me if the **specific** subclass that actually gets instantiated at some point *overrides* that empty method `setPermissions()` - based on the underlying OS for example.

In any case, there is a simple, but ugly workaround: use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and run

```
hadoop fs -chmod a+w path//to//folder
```

from within Java. And write down:

```
// TODO: check with next version of hadoop if fs.FileSystem.setPermission() is now implemented
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the mkdirs command doesn't set the file permissions, as per the JavaDoc

Comment: @cricket_007 Well. I did do some searching on grepcode ... and I too only found an empty setPermissions() method. And the subclass I checked did not override either ...

Comment: Very strange... https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#L2337. Makes me curious how the `-chmod` flag actually works, then

Comment: Thank U, actually I was looking for some code based solution, but this suggestion working fine, thank you :)